# Make the function immutable

Tags: javascript

I build following method that change the structure of the input objects. It works but I would like to make it immutable.

```
function formatObj(obj: Object) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj)

  keys.forEach((key) => {
    const value = obj[key]

    if (value === null || value === undefined) {
      return
    }
    else if (key === 'size') {
      obj[key] = { value, min: 0, max: 0 }
    }
    else if (typeof value === 'object') {
      formatObj(obj[key])
    }
  })
}
```

I tried this but it returns a list of undefined...

```
function formatObj(obj: Object) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj)

  const r = keys.map((key) => {
    const value = obj[key]

    if (value === null || value === undefined) {
      return { key: value }
    }
    else if (key === 'size') {
      return { key: { value, min: 0, max: 0 } }
    }
    else if (typeof value === 'object') {
      return formatObj(obj[key])
    }
  })

  return r
}
```

Why? How can I solve?

Comment: Please share sample data.

Comment: In the `map`, there's no return for every scenario. You might want to look at that, since the default return value of a function is `undefined`.

Comment: For example, what happens when `key !== 'size'` and `typeof value !== 'object'`?

Comment: Are you trying to make to object immutable after it was changed by the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiom you're looking for is `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(...).map...)`:

```js
let mapObject = (obj, fn) => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => fn(k, v))
);

//

let test = {
    a: 0,
    size: 123,
    sub: {
        b: null,
        size: 456
    }
}

let transformer = (key, value) => {
    if(key === 'size')
        return [key, { value, min: 0, max: 0 }];
    if(!value || typeof value !== 'object')
        return [key, value];
    return [key, mapObject(value, transformer)]
}

let test2 = mapObject(test, transformer)

console.log(test2)
```

One drawback of this is that you have to have an external `transformer` variable to be able to reapply it. A nicer approach would be to define the transformer inside the mapper and pass it around as an argument. Also, it won't hurt to make it a bit more generic:

```js
function transform(obj, fn) {
    function transformer(x) {
        if (!x || typeof x !== 'object')
            return x;

        if (Array.isArray(x))
            return x
                .map((v, k) => fn(k, v, transformer))
                .filter(x => x !== void 0)
                .map(x => x[1]);

        return Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(x)
                .map(([k, v]) => fn(k, v, transformer))
                .filter(x => x !== void 0));
    }
    
    return transformer(obj);
}

//

let test = {
    a: 0,
    size: 123,
    removeMe: 123,
    renameMe: 456,
    sub: {
        b: null,
        size: 456,
        removeMe: 1230,
        renameMe: 4560,
        sub2: {
            foo: ['bar', 'baz', {size: 798}]
        }
    }
}

let test2 = transform(test, (key, value, transformer) => {
    // return undefined to remove a key
    if (key === 'removeMe')
        return;
        
    // return a new key
    if (key === 'renameMe')
        return ['renamed!', value];
        
    // return a new value
    if (key === 'size')
        return [key, {value, min: 0, max: 0}];
        
    // keep transforming
    return [key, transformer(value)]
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(test2,0,4))
```

`Object.fromEntries` is relatively [new](https://caniuse.com/#search=fromEntries), but can be trivially polyfilled.

Answer (score 0):

result of a Array `map` function is a list. In this case you probably want to use reduce function to make result object again. It would help better to understand if you provided some sample input and output data.

```
function formatObj(obj: Object) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj)

  const r = keys.reduce((resultObj, key) => {
    const value = obj[key]

    if (value === null || value === undefined) {
      return { ...resultObj, [key]: value }
    }
    else if (key === 'size') {
      return { ...resultObj, [key]: { value, min: 0, max: 0 } }
    }
    else if (typeof value === 'object') {
      return { ...resultObj, [key]: formatObj(obj[key]) }
    }
  }, {})

  return r
}
```